# Change in Xml layout not reflected in R.java

Tags: android

How to make a change in layout xml also reflected in R.java? I mean if I edit main_activity.xml that generated in eclipse when I creating new project with some xml code from other file (other project), how can I apply this change to R.java that created previously (previous layout when creating new project) so I can call all variable that declared in newer layout. Or is possible to call all variable in xml layout without referencing to R.java?

Answer (score 1):

`R.java` is generated automatically with the contents of your `res` folder, but if you are having some trouble try using `clean` to force `R` to be regenerated

Answer (score 0):

if you just changed the `main_activity.xml`, first be sure of don´t have any errors inside your  `/res` folder, open the "problems" window in eclipse, if there are any issues in any of the .xml files, `R.java` will not generate. 
I think most of the problems that can´t be generated are related to errors inside `/res` folder, then `Project` -> `Clean`

Answer (score 0):

As @Jorge Alfaro pointed out `R.java` is generated automatically.But if there is some error in your xml file `R.java` will no be generated.So please check for errors in your xml file,clear the errors and build it again..